# Finding Zeroes in Sudoku

Tags: java, arrays, sudoku

I had a class assignment (it's already past) where I had to write a Sudoku solver. I was able to create a method that can solve for each missing number. But I'm having trouble creating a method to find which cells I need to solve. I'm supposed to take a 2D array and fill in the missing number (represented by 0's).
I've put some of my code below, but not all of it (even though the assignment has passed, I respect the profs wishes).

```
public class SolveSudoku {

    private static int[][] grid = new int[9][9];

    public static int[][] getSolution(int[][] grid) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            System.arraycopy(grid[i], 0, SolveSudoku.grid[i], 0, 9);
        }
        int n = getZero();
        return getSolution(n);
    }

    private static int[][] getSolution(int n) {
        if (n == 0) {
            return grid;
        }
        Cell cell = getZero();
        int row = cell.row;
        int column = cell.column;
        for (int number = 1; number <= 9; number++) {
            //checks cell using another method
            //I have booleans that return true if the number works
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static int getZero() {
        return 0;
    }

    private static class Cell {
        int cell = 0;
        int row = 0;
        int column = 0;
        int number;
    }
}
```

I have the getZero method which has to find each zero in the grid (0's represent a missing number) so I can solve it. What should I do in getZero to find the cells I need to replace?

Comment: The assignment is over, but I would still like to know what I need to do. Thanks!

Comment: `getZeroes` is expected to return both a Cell and an int, according to your code, and is actually called `getZero`. You should first make up your mind about your interface.

Comment: getZero should return an int, but I use cell inside of zeroes.

Comment: Unfortunately the result of `getZero()` is driven by what your solver algorithm needs - all 0-cells? the 'first' 0-cell? the number of 0-cells? I think you need to step back and describe/think about the solver itself first. Btw, it is a bad idea to name a method argument `n` - it is unclear what it is supposed to represent.

Comment: I changed the problem to be more descriptive. getZero finds the 0s in the grid.

Answer (score 1):

You don't check if the number is repeated in the same 3x3 square (only rows and columns).

I don't get what do you mean by "finding zeroes". In fact it is meaningless, solving the sudoku from the first row or the last one has no effect in the solution. I'll explain what did I do for the same trouble.

1. A cell is not an int, is an object. In the object I store a value (the number if it is found, 0 if not) and a boolean[9]. False means (index + 1) is discarded because it is in the same row/column/square, true means it is not decided yet. Also, 3 Lists (Vectors, Sets, whatever).
2. A list of 81 cells (you can make it a bidimensional array if you wish).
3. 9 Lists/Vectors/Sets representing rows, 9 representing columns, 9 representing square. Each of the 81 cells is assigned to its row/column/square. Inside each cell you store the references to the list to which it belongs to.
4. Now comes the execution part. In a first iteration, every time you find a non-zero (a number fixed in the sudoku), you loop through the lists to which the cell belongs. For each cell in those lists, you mark the boolean assigned to that number to false.
5. You loop through cells, each time you find a 0 you check how many of the booleans in the cell are true. If it is 1 (all other 8 possible values have been discarded), it is the value of the cell. You set it, and as in 4) you get the list to which it belongs and mark that number to false in every cells. Loop until you get a solution, or an iteration in which you cannot set any number (no solution available directly, must start with backtracking or similar).

Remember before getting at the keyboard, to have a clear idea about what the question is and how would you resolve it without a computer. If you do not know what you want to do, the computer won't help (unless you post in stackoverflow)-

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell you want to find the first 0-valued cell in `grid`. I'll define first as the first zero containing column in the lowest zero-containing row.

This can be done using a naive search:

```
private Cell getZeroCell(){
    int rz = -1;
    int cz = -1;
    outer: for(int row = 0; row < grid.length; row++){
        for(int col = 0; col < grid[row].length; col++){
            if(grid[row][col] == 0){
               rz = row;
               cz = col;
               break outer;
            }
        }
    }
    if(rz == -1 || cz == -1){
       // no zeros found
       return null;
    }else{
       // first zero found at row `rz` and column `cz`
       Cell cell = new Cell();
       cell.row = rz;
       cell.column = cz;
       return cell;
    }
}
```

Get the "number" of the first cell containing a zero (counting left to right, then top to bottom, 0-indexed):

```
private int getZeroInt(){
    int rz = -1;
    int cz = -1;
    outer: for(int row = 0; row < grid.length; row++){
        for(int col = 0; col < grid[row].length; col++){
            if(grid[row][col] == 0){
               rz = row;
               cz = col;
               break outer;
            }
        }
    }
    if(rz == -1 || cz == -1){
       // no zeros found
       return -1;
    }else{
       return rz * grid[0].length + cz;
    }
}
```

Get the number of cells containing a zero:

```
private int getNumZeros(){
    int count = 0;
    for(int row = 0; row < grid.length; row++){
        for(int col = 0; col < grid[row].length; col++){
            if(grid[row][col] == 0){
              count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: This seems close to what I need. But how would this work with an int instead of a cell?

Comment: @John: what do you want the int to represent?

Comment: @John: on a whim, here's two more functions, one that gets an indexed cell (row * 9 + col); and one that counts the number of cells containing zeros.